# Are image charges uniquely determined by a problem setup?

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

can two image charge configurations satisfy the boundary conditions of a problem and thus produce the same electric field in the region of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The whole concept of an image charge is based on this consideration actually: image charge produces the same field as the real distribution of charge. So if you, for example, call initial image charge IC1 and consider real distribution as another image charge IC2 (why not?), you'll see that they produce the same field.